# Ack/Ag does not return search result without *

Tags: grep, ack, ag

I am trying to search text in a directory and it turned out that the following syntaxes do not return any result

```
ack -i "0xabcdef" ./

ack -i "0xabcdef"

ack -i "0xabcdef" .
```

while the following command works

```
ack -i "0xabcdef" *
```

Can someone explain why that is the case? What is the significance of * . I also noticed that the directory has symbolic links

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not have to specify a directory to ack.  By default it delves into the current directory.

> I also noticed that the directory has symbolic links

Then an excellent thing to do would be to look at the manual (either `man ack` or `ack --man`) and search for "link".  The first thing you'll find is this option:

```
   --[no]follow
       Follow or don't follow symlinks, other than whatever starting files
       or directories were specified on the command line.

       This is off by default.
```

This means if you want ack to follow symlinks, you need to specify the `--follow` option.

Comment: What does * mean?

Comment: `*` is a shell glob character that means "any string".  I suggest that you find a good introduction to the Unix command line before you go any further.